# Jquery and JSON data extraction not working

Tags: jquery, json, parameters, extract

I have many long strings in below format (extracted and decoded from URL)

**1) Json string 1:**

```
Default={
    "k":"",
    "r":[
    {
        "n":"RefinableString51",
        "t":["\"????636f6d6d756e69636174696f6e7320616e64206d6564696120736563746f72\""],
        "o":"and",
        "k":false,
        "m":null
    }]
}
```

**2)  Json string 2**

```
Default={
    "k":"",
    "r":[
    {
        "n":"Author",
        "t":["\"????4861726477617265\""],
        "o":"and",
        "k":false,
        "m":null
    }]
}
```

. I need to extract Strings “RefinableString51” (need to get string after “n”:” and before “,”t”:)
 and “636f6d6d756e69636174696f6e7320616e64206d6564696120736563746f72” (need to get string after ????and before \""])
 (highlighted in bold above) from 1 without “”and take them in to two different variables. There is a common pattern in all the strings I have, as can be noticed above from 1 and 2. So I need to write a generic Jquery script that extracts similar strings.

Below script thats not working as expected.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 $(document).ready(function(){
    var decodedString = 'Default={"k":"","r":[{"n":"RefinableString51","t":["\"????  636f6d6d756e69636174696f6e7320616e64206d6564696120736563746f72\""],"o":"and","k":false,"m":null}]}';   
    var data = $.parseJSON(decodedString);                      
    alert(data.r[0].n); 
    alert(data.Default.r[0].n);
    alert(data.Default.r[0].t); 
    alert(data.r[0].t);                   
 });
</script>
```

But above script is not working. Not sure what’s wrong with it.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Looks like your JSON isn't correct, fixing a few parts makes it work: http://jsfiddle.net/PMc7Q/

Comment: The JSON is valid; there's an array on t! See my answer.

Comment: Thanks Joe for the fast response. That really helped:-)

Answer (score 0):

For t use:

```
Default.r[0].t[0].substring(5).replace(/"/, '');
```

And for n use:

```
Default.r[0].n
```

for sample 1; similarly for sample 2.

[THIS DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/dH8VJ/1/) shows the above code at work. :)